# How to call a service in angular APP_Initializer?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I want to load api data before app onInit(). I am not able to inject the service dependency.

How I can inject that?

```js
import { GetComissionService } from '../app/services/get-comission.service';


function initializeApp(comissionService: GetCommissionService): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    GetComissionService.getCommission('item').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      resolve();
     })
  });
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    deps: [GetComissionService],
    useFactory: () => initializeApp,
    multi: true
   }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

> EDIT 1: adding error message images

Getting these errors while injecting service

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should also call `resolve()` after you get the data from your service.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I added but I am having issue while injecting the dependency. Its giving error

Answer (score 1):

You also need to have a parameter on the `initializeApp` function for the service. Try this:

```
export function initializeApp(comissionService: GetComissionService): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    comissionService.getCommission('item').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      resolve();
     })
  });
}
```

Comment: While adding parameter it says `Cannot find name 'GetCommissionService'` so removed it.

Comment: @IamGrooot, How do you provide `GetComissionService` for your module?

Comment: @sharko I have updated the question with error message picture. Please check

Comment: Please note that what my snippet uses is actually the parameter of the function, not the type name as you are using there. Please try to replace your whole function with the snippet I posted (using copy and paste).

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I am referring that only. Please check the updated question with error message

Comment: I have checked the updated question, and also the error message. You cannot use the class name to call the methods that you wrote inside that class. This is what instances are for. In the snippet I posted, the Angular injector is going to provide an instance of `GetComissionService` as the first parameter of the `initializeApp` method. I named the service instance `comissionService` and that is how I refer to it inside the function body. In the snippet you posted, you are still using the class name which is `GetComissionService`. I hope this is clear.

Comment: I made a typo, I added an extra `m` in the word `comission`. Please remove one of the extra `m`s and you should be good. I also updated the answer.